# ReactJs Checkbox - cannot uncheck

Tags: javascript, checkbox, reactjs

I am trying to set the checked prop of a checkbox using a state, updated code with handleChange function:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        selected:0,
        contactId: 0
    };
},

handleChange: function(e) {
    var id = this.state.contactId;

    console.log(e.target.checked);

    if (e.target.checked === true){

        console.log('selected');

        contactChannel.publish({
                    channel: "contact",
                    topic: "selectedContact",
                    data: {
                        id: [id]
                    }});

    } else{

        basketChannel.publish({
            channel: "basket",
            topic: "removePersonFromBasket",
            data: {
                id: [id]
            }
        });


        console.log('deselected flag');


    }
},
render: function() {

    var id = this.state.contactId;
    var isSelected = this.state.selected;

    console.log(isSelected);

    return (
        <div className="contact-selector">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   checked={isSelected}
                onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

However, once the checkbox is checked by default I cannot uncheck it, can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you add the `handleChange` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `handleChange` function you are always using the same value for the state of the check box but you need to reverse it.

add this to your handleChange function:

```
handleChange:function(event){
    this.setState({selected: !this.state.selected}); //look at the !NOT sign

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you return with the wrong variable. Changing `{isSelected}` with `{this.state.selected}` should work.

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        selected:0,
        contactId: 0
    };
},


render: function() {

    var id = this.state.contactId;
    var isSelected = this.state.selected;

    console.log(isSelected);

    return (
        <div className="contact-selector">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   checked={this.state.selected}
                onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: And why is that? They have the same value.

Comment: Changed to checked={this.state.selected}, and still cannot uncheck, any ideas?

Comment: I am sorry, I tried... I'm from another world than ReactJS and the recomputation is done only on the returned string... Hence why the isSelected would have always same value...

Answer (score -1):

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        selected:0,
        contactId: 0
    };
},

handleChange:function(event){
    this.setState({selected: !this.state.selected});
    isSelected = this.state.selected;

    console.log(isSelected);
}

render: function() {

    var id = this.state.contactId;
    var isSelected = this.state.selected;

    console.log(isSelected);

    return (
        <div className="contact-selector">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   checked={isSelected}
                onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: That will just keep on having the same value again.